# How to get string after xpath

Tags: php

I have this html page:

```
<div class="table_container p402_hide " id="div_Summer">
<table class=" stats_table" id="Summer">
<colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup>
<thead>
<tr class="">
  <th data-stat="year" align="right"  class=" sort_default_asc" >Year</th>
  <th data-stat="city" align="left"  class=" sort_default_asc" >City</th>
  <th data-stat="country" align="left"  class=" sort_default_asc" >Country</th>
  <th data-stat="countries" align="right"  class="" >Countries</th>
  <th data-stat="participants" align="right"  class="" >Participants</th>
  <th data-stat="participants_men" align="right"  class="" >Men</th>
  <th data-stat="participants_women" align="right"  class="" >Women</th>
  <th data-stat="sports" align="right"  class="" >Sports</th>
  <th data-stat="events" align="right"  class="" >Events</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr  class="">
   <td align="right" ><a href="/olympics/summer/2012/">2012</a></td>
   <td align="left"  csk="London:2012">London</td>
   <td align="left"  csk="Great Britain:2012">Great Britain</td>
   <td align="right" >205</td>
   <td align="right" >10,519</td>
   <td align="right" >5,864</td>
   <td align="right" >4,655</td>
   <td align="right" >32</td>
   <td align="right" >302</td>
</tr>
```

To extract the text I used this code written in PHP 7:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/');

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query('//div[@id="div_Summer"]');


var_dump($result->item(0)->nodeValue);

?>
```

In this way I get this result:

```
string(2148) "
Year
  City
  Country
  Countries
  Participants
  Men
  Women
  Sports
  Events
2012
   London
   Great Britain
   205
   10,519
   5,864
   4,655
   32
   302

"
```

I would like only this text: "2012" and "London". How could I extract this information from $result?

Comment: Why not just a more specific xpath expression?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to query the `td(s)` you're interested in directly?
Try using a more specific xpath expression, like this:

```
$result = $xpath->query('(//div[@id="div_Summer"]//tbody//tr//td[position() >= 1 and position() <= 2])');
```

And then processing them through a simple loop:

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $element) {
    var_dump($element->nodeValue);
}
?>
```

**Full example**, based on your code:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/');

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query('(//div[@id="div_Summer"]//tbody//tr//td[position() >= 1 and position() <= 2])');

foreach ($result as $element) {
    var_dump($element->nodeValue);
}

?>
```

Output (truncated):

```
string(4) "2012"
string(6) "London"
string(4) "2008"
string(7) "Beijing"
string(4) "2004"
[..]
```

Comment: I tried to use that xpath expression but I get NULL as value when I print with var_dump

Comment: @Idro i've added a full example. Are you sure you have **allow_url_fopen** set to 1 in your php.ini file?

Comment: I don't know, I will check this evening